# Inverse function theorem for partial derivatives of a vector function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a simple vector function:

$$\mathbf{y} = a\mathbf{x}\qquad a\in\mathbb{R},\;\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$$

The inverse is obviously:

$$\mathbf{y}^{-1} = {1\over a}\mathbf{x}$$

The inverse function theorem (at least for scalars) states that:

$$\left[f^{-1}(y)\right]'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}$$

But the partial derivatives of $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{y}^{-1}$ with respect to $a$ are not related that way:

$$\begin{align}(\mathbf{y})'_a &= \mathbf{x} \\ (\mathbf{y}^{-1})'_a &= -{1\over a^2}\mathbf{x} \end{align}$$

What is the relation between the above derivatives, then?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ at point x, is (= can be seen as) the jacobian matrix

$$J_F(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1}(x) & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n}(x)\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \dfrac{\partial F_n}{\partial x_1}(x) & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial F_n}{\partial x_n}(x) \end{pmatrix}$$

And the Jacobian of $F^{-1}$ at point x is the inverse of the Jacobian of $F$ at point x :

$$J_{F^{-1}}(x) = \left(J_F(x)\right)^{-1}$$

You can read this page for a little more information : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: I read that page but it does not speak about partial derivatives. The partial derivative w.r.t. to $a$ of that vector function is a vector, not matrix. But vectors are not invertible.

Comment: The Jacobian gives you the partial derivatives...

Comment: But the function is something like $\mathbf{y}=a\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}ax_1 \\ ax_2\end{pmatrix}$. The only variable I care about is $a$ ($\mathbf{x}$ is known and fixed), but using the above jacobian, there are three columns $a,x_1,x_2$ and only two rows...

Comment: Oh, you mean your function is from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$? If it's the case, it's clearly not invertible : $$f\left(1,\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = 1\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = f\left(2,\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right)$$

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I already know values of $F$, $F'_{a}$ and $F^{-1}$ and only need to somehow obtain $F'_a(F^{-1})$ using the reciprocal rule...

Comment: So the answer is actually it is not possible to use the inverse function theorem solely for partial derivatives right?

Comment: Your formula is incorrect. The LHS is $J_{F^{-1}}(F(x))$.

Answer (score -3):

The derivative w.r.t. $a$ is

$${\mathbb{d}\mathbf{y}\over \mathbb{d}a} = \mathbf{x}$$

and the derivative of inverse is the reciproval of above, i.e.

$${\mathbb{d}a\over \mathbb{d}\mathbf{y}} = {1\over \mathbf{x}}$$

The notation caused confusion about what is the inverse function. The inverse is function of $a$.

Comment: What is $1/\mathbf x$ when $\mathbf x$ is a vector?